# How can I programmatically invoke onUserInteraction in Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am looking for some ways to programmatically call `onUserInteraction`. Actually when I perform any click it is called, but if I programmatically call `performClick()` on any of the views it is not getting invoked, although the click is performed. I also tried by sending touch events through adb.

So, my question is can I programmatically invoke the `onUserInteraction` by doing some interactions inside the code.

I guess I have to do something that will make the OS think it is an actual user action.

actually I want to replay some events. So when one event happens I wait for the onUserInteraction callback to dispatch another event. Otherwise the views will not be inflated properly and the next view (the action to be performed) might not be yet available. Calling this.onUserInteraction() will not solve my problem as it will be executed in the same thread.

Comment: Can you shed some light on why you even want it to happen?

Comment: actually i want to replay some events. So when one event happens i wait for the onUserInteraction callback to dispatch another event. Otherwise the views will not be inflated properly and the next view (the action to be performed) might not be yet available.

Comment: So you basically want to cause the `Activity` to inflate it's `Views` earlier, am I right?

Comment: not like this, for example say clicking on a view will bring some changes in the UI state. I want to wait for such changes before i click the next view, because without this the next view might not be available. waiting for onUserInteraction ensures that this asynchronous call back is actually performed and the system is now on a stable state to perform my next click. I cannot do these actions sequentially in the UI thread. because it will create a blocking in the UI thread.

Comment: One temporary hack I did was creating a asynch task that wait for some milliseconds in a different thread, and on the post execute method I perform that click. In the mean time the views are inflated. But this is a very vulnerable hack.

Comment: To be honest I think I don't really understand your scenario, but for me it seems like you're trying to implement it in some really convoluted way. If you're 100% sure, the way you're trying to achieve your goal is right, edit your post, and try to explain thoroughly your case (possibly with sample images). If you're not sure, maybe try to rethink your app flow.